# Facebook open graph action returns "false"

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to post an action to open graph but the only response I'm getting is "false".

According to the "Creating and Using Actions" portion of the [API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/actions/) it appears that I'm doing this correctly.

**Code sample below.**

```
var url = facebook.root + 'objects/' + verb + '/' + noun + '.html';
var method = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/joe_longstreet:' + verb + '?' + noun + '=' + url + '&distance=' + distance + '&tags=' + users + '&access_token=' + facebook.token;
FB.api(method, 'post', function(response){
    if(response.error){
        alert(response.error.message);
    } else{
        console.log(response);
        var message = 'Posted to your timeline!';
        alert(message);
    }
});
```

Where verb = run, noun = route, and url = my objects page.
Specifically:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/joe_longstreet:run?route=http://joelongstreet.showoff.io/Facebook_app/objects/run/route.html&distance=&tags=1915805&access_token=ABCDE
```

Fake access token above. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Looks like you don't need to include the https://graph.facebook.com portion of the url. so it should just read    /me/joe_longstreet:run?route=http://joelongstreet.showoff.io/Facebook_app/objects/run/route.html&distance=&tags=1915805&access_token=ABCDE

Comment: If that solution worked, you can create a response and mark it as accepted. I don't think you get karma for it, but it makes it easier for people to find that answer in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you don't need to include the graph.facebook.com portion of the url. so it should just read /me/joe_longstreet:run?...